# Is there a way to get smaller code generation from Babel?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm seeing some less than optimal code generation in situations like this:

```
const selectedReddit = (state = 'reactjs', action) => {
  console.log(state, action);
}
```

which gets transformed into this:

```
'use strict';
var selectedReddit = function selectedReddit() {
  var state = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 'reactjs';
  var action = arguments[1];

  console.log(state, action);
};
```

Which is a pretty big code bloat, when it could have been:

```
'use strict';
function selectedReddit(state, action) {
  state = state || 'reactjs';

  console.log(state, action);
};
```

Maybe this has to do with transforming for let, but this seems a pretty expensive transpile for default arguments. Is there some code shrinking that could be applied to this output, or a different transformer that would produce smaller code?

219 characters used when 119 were required. Thats about a 45% code bloat.

[Playground example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0Aconst%20selectedReddit%20%3D%20(state%20%3D%20'reactjs'%2C%20action)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(state%2C%20action)%3B%0A%7D%0A&playground=true)

@lonesomeday pointed out this would not work for `state === false` but

```
'use strict';
function selectedReddit(state, action) {
  state = (state === undefined) ? 'reactjs' : state;

  console.log(state, action);
};
```

Which weighs in @ 160 bytes which is only a 26% code bloat.

I'm not sure why the `var funcName = function funcName` ever gets inserted and why all the arguments becomes arguments[index].

It would be great to be writing in ES6, but this almost screams DONT DO IT! if your code is going to be transpiled for the browser this way.

Comment: It couldn't be `state = state || 'reactjs';` because the original would have allowed `false`, whereas this would replace it. That might be better for you --- but it isn't what the ES6 code means.

Comment: So even when I correct for that it's still a 26% penalty over the code that could have been generated.

Comment: My guess is that it is the simplest way to code it when it comes to including rest parameters, but I agree that it seems inefficient. As to `var funcName = function funcName`, I imagine that's trying to sort out the problem of `Function.prototype.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on. Note that these are informed speculation backed by certain actual differences in behavior between what you propose and what Babel generates (which closely matches what the spec requires); I don't know the actual motivation.

- The reason for `var f = function f(){}` instead of `function f(){}` is that it avoids [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting). It doesn't matter here, but e.g. `console.log(f); var f = function f(a) { return a; };` is different from `console.log(f); function f(a) { return a; }`: the first will print `undefined`, the second will print the function.
- It needs to include the name of the function in the expression because it affects the `.name` property of the function in pre-ES6 environments (which predate function name inference). In an ES6 environment, `const f = a => a; console.log(f.name);` will print `'f'`; in pre-ES6 environments, `var f = function(a) { return a; }; console.log(f.name);` will print `''`.
- Presumably the reason it uses `arguments` instead of named formal parameters is that it affects the `.length` property of the function: `((a = 0, b) => {}).length === 0`, whereas `(function f(a, b){...}).length === 2`.
- As pointed out in the comments, `state || 'reactjs'` will give you `reactjs` when any falsey value is specified, not just `undefined`.
- The `arguments.length` check is needed in case someone defines the `0` property on `Object.prototype`: `Object.prototype[0] = 'evil'; (function f(){return arguments[0] !== 'undefined' ? arguments[0] : 'default'; })()` will return `'evil'` instead of `'default'`.

Babel historically generated code closer to what you've written, back in the 6to5 days. It turned out that a compiler which generates code which is only *mostly* semantically the same as what you've written is a very painful compiler to use.

As to your actual question, Babel has the `es2015-loose` preset, but it won't affect the code you've written. On the whole, the value of generating *correct* code usually outweighs the value of generating shorter code.

Comment: I've gone back to using mostly ES5 now and react functional components.  It's shaved about 3.5-4K off what used to be 24K of code uglified code (according to source-map-explorer).  I had figured it would be somewhat larger code, but did not expect 16-20% larger code.  I guess for the time being that's going to be what I have to do.  Forcing me back to ES5 was a big win though in that it got me looking at how many of my components could actually be functional components and don't even need createClass.